# Simulate rotating a board

Tags: code-golf, simulation

## Introduction

You're playing a matching game, in which coins are inserted at the top and fall to the bottom (onto the top coin) due to gravity.

So this

```
O <- inserting this coin

OO O
OOOOO
```

will become this

```
O
OO O
OOOOO
```

Now imagine someone rotates the board clockwise. The following will happen:

#### 1. The board is rotated

```
OOO
OO
O
OO
O
```

#### 2. Coins fall down due to gravity

```
O
O
OO
OO
OOO
```

## Your task

Your task is to simulate the rotation of the board by writing a program or a function. For the sake of simplicity we're only dealing with one kind of coin (it's not a too exciting matching game, is it…). You can assume that gravity is applied only after the rotation is complete. The board is rotated clockwise.

## Input

The input is going to be a string, which contains 3 types of characters:

- O (capital o) OR 0 (zero) - a coin (you decide which one your solution supports)
- (space) - an empty field
- \n (new line) - end of row

The input represents the state of the board. You can assume, the input is well formed and contains a valid state of the board (no coins are floating).
The input can be a function parameter, or can be read from the standard input or from a file.

## Output

The output is the new state of the board after rotation. The output contains the same 3 types of characters as the input. The output can be returned from your function or can be written to the standard output or to a file.

## Sample

Input1:

```
O
OO O
OOOOO
```

Output1:

```
O
O
OO
OO
OOO
```

Input2:

```
O O
O O
```

Output2:

```
OO
OO
```

You can use any language and the standard library of the chosen language. Shortest program in bytes wins.

Comment: Are the shorter lines padded with trailing spaces?

Comment: If you need so then yes.

Comment: What are the requirements for the board size? Can I choose a reasonable maximum size, or does the application/function need to work for all possible sizes?

Comment: You can assume that the maximum size of the board is 50x50

Comment: Does any part of the task involve matching?

Comment: @user2357112 no

Comment: If gravity is applied after rotation, how does Input2 become Output2? I would have thought it would drop the top coins down but not horizontally?

Comment: I think the correct output2 should be two piles of two coins separated by one empty column.

Comment: @Matt Note, that there are no empty rows in Input2, nor in Output2 (SE displays margin between the rows).

Comment: @justhalf `You can assume, the input is well formed and contains a valid state of the board (no coins are floating)` It's actually impossible to get a blank column sandwiched between non-blank columns

Comment: Yes, I thought there was an empty row in the input.

Comment: @David Frank, you are right, makes sense now! The empty column along with what looked like the empty row was confusing (to me!).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### GolfScript, <strike>14</strike> 12 characters

```
' '-n%zip$n*
```

Input must be given on STDIN, the character for coins can be any non-whitespace characters. Try [here](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OydPCk9PIE8KT09PT08nCgonICctbiV6aXAkbioK&run=true). Thanks to Peter for pointing out a two character reduction.

Comment: Oh, what I wouldn't give for a `transpose` in Ruby that can handle arrays with different lengths ...

Comment: @Ventero Most of the times I use this hacky version: `([nil]*a.map(&:size).max).zip(*a)`. Not good for golfing though.

Comment: You can save 2 chars: since the longest lines always end up at the bottom, you can replace `-1%` with `$`.

Comment: @PeterTaylor You're right - we can save to chars. Thank you.

Comment: The CJam translation has 9 characters, but it's way too similar so I hesitate to post it :p

Comment: @aditsu, you designed CJam, didn't you? Why didn't you include a one-character alias for `' '`?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Well, I did include a one-character alias for `" "`.

Answer (score 6):

### Ruby 2.0, 59 characters

```
puts$<.map(&:chars).reverse.transpose.sort[1,50].map &:join
```

Input via stdin, assumes lines all have the same length. This is probably much longer than necessary. But at least it's readable ...

Comment: I think you can use `$<.map` instead.

Comment: @Howard That's one thing I *always* forget. Thanks!

Comment: what is [1,50] doing there?

Comment: @Charles It skips the first row, which contains all the newlines from the input. David mentioned in a comment that 50x50 is the maximum possible size, so instead of selecting all but the first row (`1..-1`), I just select 50 rows starting with the second one (`1,50`).

Comment: @Ventero got it.  cool. thanks!

Answer (score 6):

## Javascript (E6) 103

First try, just matrix operations. Each row in input string need to be padded.
Quite wordy.

```
R=t=>(x=t.split('\n').reverse().map(x=>[...x].sort()),x.map((c,i)=>x.map(r=>r[i]).join('')).join('\n'))
```

**Pseudo code**

1. string -> array of rows
2. up/down reverse array
3. each row -> char array
4. sort each row (coins 'fall' to right)
5. transpose
6. each char array in a row -> a string
7. join array -> single string

Comment: Oh wow, sorting is smart (+1)! Mind if I steal it?

Comment: I've never seen the syntax `[...x]` before. What is it called?

Comment: @ComFreak it's called `spread` [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator]

Comment: @edc65 You broke your own link with brackets. Here is the [correct link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

Answer (score 3):

### J - <s>49</s> <s>31</s> 24 bytes

I think there might be unnecessary rotations in there, but otherwise it works fine. It's a function that takes the input as specified, coins being `O`. No trailing whitespace is required in the input.

New version, inspired by [edc65's Javascript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/32644/20356):

```
f=:[:|."1@|:[:/:~"1,;._2
```

Explanation:

```
f=:[:|."1@|:[:/:~"1,;._2
                   ,;._2 Split the string at every fret, which is the last character in the string (newline).
              /:~"1      Sort every row separately.
     |."1@|:             Rotate the array clockwise.
```

---

Old version:

```
f=:[:|:((#~=&' '),=&'O'#])"1@|:@(|."1@|:)@(,;._2)
```

Explanation:

```
f=:[:|:((#~=&' '),=&'O'#])"1@|:@(|."1@|:)@(,;._2)
                                          (,;._2) Split the string at every fret, which is the last character in the string (newline).
                                (|."1@|:)@        Rotate the array clockwise.
                             |:@                  Reverse the axes (columns become rows and vice-versa).
       ((#~=&' '),=&'O'#])"1                      Function that applies the "gravity"
                          "1                       Apply to every row separately:
                  =&'O'#]                           Get the O's in the row.
       (#~=&' ')                                    Get the spaces in the row.
                ,                                   Join them, spaces come first.
  [:|:                                            Reverse axes again.
```

---

Examples (note that multiline strings start with `0 : 0` and end withh a bracket):

```
   f 0 : 0
O
OO O
OOOOO
) NB. output starts now
O  
O  
OO 
OO 
OOO
   f 0 : 0
O O
O O
) NB. Output starts now.
  
OO
OO
```

Comment: If you can, sort before rotate

Comment: @edc65 You're a smart man.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2 (69) <strike>(79)</strike>

```python
for c in sorted(zip(*raw_input().split("\\n"))):print''.join(c[::-1])
```

Takes input padded with spaces so all lines have equal length. The `split` creates an arrat of each line. The `zip` effectively transposes the array. Then, the `sorted` sorts tuples in lexicographic order, causing all coins to fall to the bottom. Finally, we print each line, turning it back into a string, though we must reverse it first. Doing `print'O'*c.count('O')` is equivalent and uses the same number of characters.

Example run:

```
>> O    \nOO O \nOOOOO
O
O
OO
OO
OOO
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Haskell — 86

Just learning, so I'm sure this can be improved.

```
import Data.List
c=putStr.unlines.filter(/="").sort.map(filter(/=' ')).transpose.lines
```

Sample Input:

```
let a = "O    \nOO O \nOOOOO"
let b = " O O \n O O "
c a
c b
```

Sample Output:

```
O
O
OO
OO
OOO

OO
OO
```

Answer (score 1):

### C, <s>167</s> 119 bytes

This shorter version is (unfortunately?) much clearer than the original too.

```
m;j;b[99];r;main(){while(j=getchar()+1)j-11?m+=j-33&&++b[r]>m:++r;for(j=r;m+1;putchar(j--?m<b[j]?79:32:(j=r,m--,10)));}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Racket: 130

```scm
(let l((a'()))(let((b(sort(string->list(read-line))char<?)))(if
(null? b)(apply map(λ x(map display x)(newline))a)(l(cons b a)))))
```

It requires you pad with spaces so the lines are equal lemgth.

Answer (score 0):

### C# - <s>209</s> 174 bytes

Right, I have to try this Code golf at some point I reckon. Created a function (r) that rotates the board and prints it. I guess I'm cheating a little when I am printing my char array, but if you cannot figure out why you shouldn't be mad :)

Thanks to ProgramFOX for the tips :)

```c#
void r(string s){int x=s.IndexOf('\n'),j,i=-1,k,z=x+1;var y=new char[x*x+x];for(;++i<x;y[z*(i+1)-1]='\n')for(k=j=x;j>0;)if(s[i*z+--j]=='0')y[k--*z-i-2]='0';Console.Write(y);}
```

Cheat

> `new char[x*x+x]` fills the array with `'\0'` and not `' '`

Comment: Removing the newlines and removing the space between `char[]` and `y` will reduce your character count to 192 characters. Also, it is not really necessary to provide the keyword `static` when posting an answer here. Removing it will reduce your character count to 185 characters.

Comment: I was also able to remove 'ref ' which was forgotten there since an earlier try.