# Rotate a grid 90 degrees clockwise

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art

The task is simple, given an integer `n` of how many lines the next `n` lines is and, a multi-line input, output the resulting 90 degree tilted grid in a clockwise formation.

E.g.

Input:

```
2
c d
o e
```

Output:

```
o c
e d
```

I/O format:

1. Input will have spaces in between them
2. Input always contains alphabetical characters except the first input `n`

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins!

Credit: https://www.codingame.com/contribute/view/727778c431888fc6c0d03c77037ad93c3fa4 by Tsloa

Comment: The [tag:code-challenge] tag is only for questions with non-standard scoring systems. It shouldn't be used in combination with [tag:code-golf]

Comment: ah ic sry pxeger

Comment: This is also not very clear. What do you mean by "a so-called grid"? Will it always be a multi-line string of letters? Will it always have spaces between the cells? This is why we strongly recommend you post your challenges in [the sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140): to sort out these problems before you post them on the main site. A lot of your past challenges have been poorly received, so *please* use the sandbox in future.

Comment: problem is basically onle fmbeula checks and very few people even comment in the first place in sandbox

Comment: Leave your post in the sandbox for several days, and then you will be more likely to get any feedback. If you get no comments, and just some upvotes, it's probably a good challenge; if you get none whatsoever, you can also ask for feedback explicitly in [our chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rotate 2D Array](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/32851/rotate-2d-array)

Comment: no it does not pygamer this is different with no lists in input

Comment: Can we take an array of lines (and ignore the first number) or an array of arrays of characters?

Comment: Since multi-line strings [may be treated as lists of one-line strings](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17095), and since strings are basically lists of characters, this is essentially the same as a 2D array. I disagree that this should be closed as a duplicate of that one, though, because that one is already closed, and there isn't really a point in that.

Comment: you most likely have to split the input due to the spaces in between chars

Comment: Is this challenge from another site?

Comment: That seems to be based on [a clash from codingame](https://www.codingame.com/contribute/view/727778c431888fc6c0d03c77037ad93c3fa4). I'm not sure about the licensing of those, but you should definitely credit the original author

Comment: thx ovs i had trouble finding that link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), 6 (or 7?) [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
|€#øí»
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/5lHTGuXDOw6vPbT7//9khRSufIVUAA)

It doesn't need the length as input, but if it's mandatory for whatever reason, you can add a `¦` after the `|` to simply remove it from the list of inputs:
[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/5tCyR01rlA/vOLz20O7//424khVSuPIVUgE)

Could be 2 bytes with standard I/O:
[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8I7Da///j45WSlbSUUpRitWJVsoHslKVYmMB)

**Explanation (of the 7 bytes program):**

```python
|        # Get all lines of input as a list
 ¦       # Remove the first item (the additional length)
  €#     # Split each line on spaces
    øí   # Rotate the matrix 90 degrees clockwise:
    ø    #  Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns
     í   #  Reverse each inner row
      »  # Join each inner list by spaces, and then these strings by newlines
         # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 7 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

[`z` would work on its own](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=eg&input=ImMgZAoKbyBlIg) if the spacing between characters and lines were consistent.

```
·m¸z m¸
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=t224eiBtuA&input=ImMgZApvIGUi)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 8 bytes

```
ＦＮ↓⟦⟦⁻Ｓ `
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBwzOvoLTErzQ3KbVIQ1NTIaAoM69Ew8olvzxPRyE62jczr7QYoia4BCiVrqGpo6CkoKQZG6tp/f@/EVeyQgpXvkLqf92yHAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＦＮ
```

Input the number of lines and loop that many times:

```
↓⟦⟦⁻Ｓ `
```

Remove spaces from the next line of input, then output it vertically and move the cursor two spaces leftwards.

Answer (score 0):

## Python3, 60 bytes

```
_,*R=map(str.split,open(0))
for r in zip(*R[::-1]):print(*r)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/#python3)

Comment: Why do you think it needs to be a one-liner?

Comment: hmm? i didnt say that im saying if i could i would but i cant (as a one liner u can use lambda)

Comment: You can just submit it as a full program: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P15HK8g2N7FAo7ikSK@4ICezRCe/IDVPw0BTkystv0ihSCEzT6Eqs0BDKyjaykrXMFbTqqAoM69EQ6tI8///fIVkrlSFFC4A "Python 3 – Try It Online"). Except that your answer doesn't seem to work, because it always ignores the first line of input. You can change `_,*R` to `*R,` to fix this

Comment: sry i changed the IO format of the qns

Answer (score 0):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 89 bytes

```
[[print1(c,if(j--," ","\n"))|c<-r]|r<-Mat(Colrev([Vec(Str(input))|i<-[1..n=input]])),j=n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcqxCoMwEADQ3a8ImS6QC9g5Ts5OgkuaQdK0nMgZjujkv6el6@OVVQg/pbUQihDXHpKlN2yIVitt9ZO1MXfyKPEWj9NaYTx2yReEJSeYqwBxOesvkcfQO8fDH2I0xm4Dx9YeXVKv7lD5Cw)

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) 2.13.0, 71 bytes

```
[print(strjoin(r," "))|r<-Mat(Colrev([Vec(Str(input))|i<-[1..input]]))]
```

The newest version of PARI/GP finally has a `strjoin` function. But no TIO.